# Как с помощью скрипта сделать плавную и рандомную смену background-image у блока с фиксированным фоном?

Tags: jquery

Есть следующая конструкция:

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}

.bgchange {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url(https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg);
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
/* картинки для смены основного background:
https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/002.jpg;
https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/003.jpg;
https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/004.jpg;
*/

.bgchange p {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 130%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p>Синдром кота - это когда ты долго долбишься в закрытую дверь, а когда ее наконец открывают, задумываешься о том, а нужно ли оно тебе вообще, зачем долбиться-то надо было?</p>
  <div class="bgchange">
    <p>И только много лет спустя, обзаведясь женой и многочисленным семейством, Робинзон Крузо понял, что прожил 28 лет на острове свободы.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Мэт Дарлинг - тролль высочайшего уровня. Живет он рядом с аэропортом. Пока был молодой и спал крепко, самолеты его не сильно беспокоили, но с годами у него развилась чувствительнось к шуму, и он почти перестал спать. Поэтому Мэт на крыше своего дома
    вывел огромную надпись "Добро пожаловать в Кливлэнд". И все бы хорошо, но он живет в Милуоки. Пассажиры самолетов заходящих на посадку устраивали форменные истерики, увидев надпись и решив что прилетели не туда, в связи с чем, летчики стали облетать
    его дом стороной и престарелый тролль смог нормально высыпаться...)</p>
</div>
```

У блока с классом `bgchange` требуется плавно (прозрачность, плавно перетекающая в следующее изображение) менять фоновое изображение с заданным интервалом. Перечень картинок, на какие менять, есть в css коде конструкции. При этом необходимо чтобы при каждой загрузке/обновлении страницы первая фоновая картинка рандомно менялась. Также важно чтобы свойство `background-attachment: fixed;` сохранилось т.е. при прокрутке страницы фон оставался в одном и том же положении (пример для наглядности скролится).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать эту задачу в виде скрипта?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть кому-то пригодится:
Для себя решил исходную задачу (кроме рандомной смены изображения при обновлении страницы) с помощью скрипта "Vegas Background Ver.2"

**Порядок действий:**

1) Скачать (с сайта разработчика) и подключить (к вашему сайту) скрипт JS `vegas.min.js`

2) Аналогично скачать и подключить css `vegas.min.css`

3) Добавить функцию вызова (как в примере) с необходимыми настройками. На сайте разработчика в документации к слову море всевозможных настроек для скрипта (анимация, переходы, доп. оформление и др.)

4) Добавить в ваш css правило `.vegas-slide-inner {background-attachment: fixed!important;}`

```js
$(function() {
    $('.bgchange').vegas({
    delay: 2500,
    timer: false,
    transition: 'fade',
    transitionDuration: 800,
        slides: [
            { src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/001.jpg' },
            { src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/002.jpg' },
            { src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/003.jpg' },
            { src: 'https://s4.wampi.ru/2017/09/11/004.jpg' }
        ]
    });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 500px;
  width: 80%;
}

.vegas-slide-inner {
    background-attachment: fixed!important;
}

.bgchange {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}


.bgchange p {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 130%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vegas/2.4.0/vegas.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jaysalvat.github.io/vegas/releases/latest/vegas.min.css">

<div class="parent">
  <p>Синдром кота - это когда ты долго долбишься в закрытую дверь, а когда ее наконец открывают, задумываешься о том, а нужно ли оно тебе вообще, зачем долбиться-то надо было?</p>
  <div class="bgchange">
    <p>И только много лет спустя, обзаведясь женой и многочисленным семейством, Робинзон Крузо понял, что прожил 28 лет на острове свободы.</p>
  </div>
  <p>Мэт Дарлинг - тролль высочайшего уровня. Живет он рядом с аэропортом. Пока был молодой и спал крепко, самолеты его не сильно беспокоили, но с годами у него развилась чувствительнось к шуму, и он почти перестал спать. Поэтому Мэт на крыше своего дома
    вывел огромную надпись "Добро пожаловать в Кливлэнд". И все бы хорошо, но он живет в Милуоки. Пассажиры самолетов заходящих на посадку устраивали форменные истерики, увидев надпись и решив что прилетели не туда, в связи с чем, летчики стали облетать
    его дом стороной и престарелый тролль смог нормально высыпаться...)</p>
</div>
```